# Refactoring a class based component into a functional component with Redux and useDispatch is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to learn useDispatch to refacture a class component. Dispatch is working sometimes, but not others. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong...

dev-tools:
[image: what redux dev tools says]

component:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import {
    hideAllComps,
    newSearchLocation,
    logFullSearchName,
} from '../../../../actions';

function SearchBar() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const hideAllCompsState = useSelector((state) => state.hideOrShow);
    const currentLocation = useSelector((state) => state.location);
    const searchedLocation = useSelector((state) => state.searchedLocation);

....


function logNewSearchLocation(response) {
        dispatch(newSearchLocation(response));
        console.log(searchedLocation); // logs 'none'
    }

    function searchLocation(city) {
        let key = `XXX`;
        let coord = ['lat', 'lon'];
        let site = `XXX`;
        axios
            .get(site)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response); // results are there
                logNewSearchLocation(response);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                alert(err);
            });
    }
```

My action:

```
export const newSearchLocation = (loc) => {
    return {
        type: 'NEW_SEARCH_LOCATION',
        payload: loc,
    };
};
```

my reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

...

const searchedLocation = (loc = 'none', action) => {
    if (action.type === 'NEW_SEARCH_LOCATION') {
        return action.payload;
    } else {
        return loc;
    }
};

....
const weatherApp = combineReducers({
    ...
    searchedLocation: searchedLocation,
    ...
});

export default weatherApp;
```

it was working fine with Redux in the class based component using mapStateToProps and all that. I want to learn to move away from class based and get into hooks. I really appreciate the help...

Comment: I suggest using Redux Devtools (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=de)  to debug your redux code. Your code looks fine to me, for us to help we need to know what's wrong (eg: The dispatch isn't being executed or the dispatch works, but the state isn't changed).

Comment: @TimGerhard - First of all, thank you for telling me about the dev-tools they are amazing, and they kind of blow my mind all together.

Comment: @TimGerhard - I have posted a screenshot, it appears to have worked, but the console.log is still no showing it

Comment: You are logging searchedLocation in logNewSearchLocation but there you are logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) log the searchedLocation when the component renders and not in a handler or hook because it'll only log stale values there.

Comment: @HMR is right. I wouldn't use a console.log() to debug a redux state change. Try putting the console.log in the return function (render function of your functional component)

Comment: @HMR  if I were to do something that that wasn’t a console.log, the information would be usable from the redux state at that point? Correct?

Comment: @RickGove maybe you can update the question with what you're trying to do. It seems that redux is working but for some reason you'd like to access the changed redux state after dispatching an action and in the same function that dispatched the action. That is only possible in a thunk action and I'm not sure why you want to do such a thing in an event handler.

Comment: @HMR to be fair, you’re right. Why woul I need to do that. Redux dev tools has solved all the problems. Thanks for your time